# Can't write to standard input

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a program using a **REPL** where we can prompt commands and I want add a feature to handle the up arrow to display the previously entered commands, just like in bash.
The problem I have is that I can't find how I can print my previous command on the standard input.

I've tried using hPutStr like this:

`hPutStr stdin "Test"`

but when I run it I encounter this error:

`<stdin>: hPutStr: illegal operation (handle is not open for writing)`

Does anyone know how to bypass this restriction or maybe just another way to print something on the standard input ?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write to the standard output? `hPutStr stdout "Test"`?

Comment: Nope, I want to write to the standard input so the user can edit what's printed before sending it back in the program through the prompt.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think you can write to stdin. You'll have to do more elaborated work to read from and write to the terminal. You might want to use a library such as haskeline or repline that provides the functionality you are looking for and more, or look at how they implement that functionality.

Comment: not sure, but if you write to stdin, how would the user read the message? If the message is displayed in the screen, then it should be redirected to stdout, isn't it?

Comment: Think of it this way. Your REPL's standard input is the read end of a pipe, the write end of which your *terminal* writes to. So it's your terminal, not the REPL, you need to interact with in order to modify what your REPL sees as input.

Comment: You can not write to the stdin, a prompt that gives you the impression that you can edit something is just a clever algorithm that writes to the stdout, and uses for example ANSI terminal commands to erase items, move the cursor, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't get where you want to go along the path you've chosen.

Instead, what you'll have to do is like this:

1. Set up stdin to be unbuffered, so that you get the user's input as soon as it happens.
2. When they hit up, print to *stdout* the thing you remember they typed last time. (Don't forget to clear away anything they've already typed first.)
3. Record somewhere, on the side, in a variable in your program, the current text of what they typed last time.
4. As you receive new input from stdin, use it to update both the text showing on the screen and the text recorded in your variable. With the default terminal settings, new letters and numbers and punctuation and the like will automatically appear on the screen, so you only need to update your variable; but you'll need to handle things like backspace specially.
5. Once the user presses enter, look at what's in your variable, instead of taking exactly what you got from stdin.

I *strongly* recommend you use a library that's already implemented and bug-checked all of this; if you write it yourself, you'll likely need to learn more about how terminals work than you really wanted to know, and even then there's really quite a lot of ways for it to go wrong.

Comment: You may very well not need a library at all: `rlwrap` does a good job externally.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t possible directly; standard input isn’t writable.

The most straightforward Haskell-only solution is to use a library that provides line editing and history for you, the most popular of which is [`haskeline`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline). Assuming for the sake of example that you have an `eval :: String -> IO Value` action, a REPL with history would look like this:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import System.Console.Haskeline
  ( InputT
  , defaultSettings
  , getInputLine
  , outputStrLn
  , runInputT
  )

repl :: IO ()
repl = runInputT defaultSettings loop
 where
   loop :: InputT IO ()
   loop = do
     entry <- getInputLine "> "        -- R
     case entry of
       Nothing -> pure ()
       Just line -> do
         result <- liftIO $ eval line  -- E
         outputStrLn $ show result     -- P
         loop                          -- L
```

`getInputLine` will produce `Nothing` when standard input is closed, if the user types the control code for EOF (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) or if input is being piped to your REPL and the pipe is closed. In addition to editing and history, Haskeline offers autocompletion, which you may find useful for a REPL.

The low-tech solution is to run your program under a wrapper that provides GNU readline-style editing, such as `rlwrap`. The fully general solution is to build your own editing using a console UI library, the most popular of which is [`brick`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick).